# Can you implement a widget that uses a <script> tag in Angular2?

Tags: jquery, widget, angular

We have an existing widget using `<script>` tags that we wrote, for third party customers to add to their site.  When added, it generates all the HTML, forms, etc for the widget.  We did this to avoid all the hassles of iframes.

From my understanding, Angular2 does not allow `<script>` tags in a template?  I assume their are many widgets that work the way ours do?  Is there some way to do this in Angular2?  Or did we miss the mark and there is a better way entirely (iframe?) to do a similar function?

The widget itself it written in jQuery, I am not sure that it matters, but it is.  I would happily re-write the widget in Angular2, but it still must "plugin" to any website.

Comment: Your are right, Angular doesn't allow `<script>` tags in templates. A widget that "avoid all the hassles of iframes" is quite vague? What are the actual requirements?

Comment: Sure, think of a script that shows you a list of available properties and allows you to view them.  You have a product that builds this logic and view for people, and you want them to be able able to use it in their own website.

This is easy, a script tag that passes in a few variables (depending on the user, maybe to choose a style).  All they need to do is paste that script tag into the page they want on their website, and tada, all of the view and logic (posts back to our server) is there.

Answer (score 2):

Angular1 would not trigger script tags from templates (unless you used jQuery as well), and Angular2 probably does about the same thing. However there is nothing stopping your from inserting the script tag with pure JS.

I have not done this in Angular2, but in Angular1 I would do something like this inside a directive.

```
document.createElement('script');
script.src = "/assets/game/dmloader.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head'[0].appendChild(script);
```

I would assume the same works in Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for the actual ng2 syntax (thanks for the idea - the logic was correct)

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Directive} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[mywidget]' })

export class MyDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
       let tag = document.createElement('script');
       tag.id = "scriptId";
       tag.setAttribute("myattr", "myvalue");
       tag.src = "https://cdn.acmeproject.org"
       this.el.nativeElement.appendChild(tag); 
     }
}
```