# Place script inside template in AngularJS 2

Tags: javascript, angular, arcgis

I should insert a script tag quite long inside a template in AngularJS 2? is it a a good idea to put a script inside a template in AngularJS 2? Where should I put? Basically it is just a script that load a map https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/search_basic.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you implement a widget that uses a <script> tag in Angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950194/can-you-implement-a-widget-that-uses-a-script-tag-in-angular2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Script tags in templates are just removed by Angular. You can dynamically create and add one after the view is created or add it to the entry page.
There is already a similar question answered but I don't have the time just yet to look it up.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/38090157/217408