# Adding script tags in Angular component template

Tags: javascript, angular, json-ld, angular2-universal

Angular2 removes `<script>` tags automatically from templates to stop people using this functionality as a ["poor's man" loader](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2766#issuecomment-128005280).

The issue here is that script tags currently have more uses than just loading code or other script files. There is the possibility that further functionality around `<script>` tags will be introduced in future as well.

One current use is JSON-LD which takes the format

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context":"http://schema.org",
    "@type":"HealthClub",
    ...
}
</script>
```

A commonly suggested work around is to [dynamically add script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35570910/981598) to the document via the `ngAfterViewInit` hook, but this is obviously not proper ng2 practice and will not work server side, which JSON-LD obviously needs to be able to do.

Are there any other workarounds that we can use to include `<script>` tags in angular2 templates (even if the tag is inert within the browser) or is this a case of the framework being too opinionated? What other solutions might exist if this situation can't be solved in angular2?

Comment: Issue reported at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9695

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Maybe a little late to the party here, but since the above answers do not work well with Angular SSR (e.g. `document is not defined` server-side or `document.createElement is not a function`), I decided to write a version that works for Angular 4+, **in both server and browser context**:

**Component Implementation**

```
import { Renderer2, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private _renderer2: Renderer2, 
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document
    ) { }

    public ngOnInit() {

        let script = this._renderer2.createElement('script');
        script.type = `application/ld+json`;
        script.text = `
            {
                "@context": "https://schema.org"
                /* your schema.org microdata goes here */
            }
        `;

        this._renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, script);
    }
}
```

**Service Implementation**

*NOTE: Services cannot use `Renderer2` directly. In fact, rendering an element **is supposed to be done by a Component**. However, you might find yourself in situation where you want to automate the creation of JSON-LD `script` tags on a page. As an example, a situation could be to invoke such function on route navigation change events. Hence I decided to add a version that works in a `Service` context.*

```
import { Renderer2, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

/**
 * Use a Service to automate creation of JSON-LD Microdata.
 */
class MyService {

    constructor(
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document
    ) { }

    /**
     * Set JSON-LD Microdata on the Document Body.
     *
     * @param renderer2             The Angular Renderer
     * @param data                  The data for the JSON-LD script
     * @returns                     Void
     */
    public setJsonLd(renderer2: Renderer2, data: any): void {

        let script = renderer2.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'application/ld+json';
        script.text = `${JSON.stringify(data)}`;

        renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, script);
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to use `Rendere2` in a service as you suggested throws the error: "*No provider for Renderer2*". See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/MpsFO4E0EkKYuyKUh328?p=preview)

Comment: The `Renderer2` is not directly usable inside a service. This is why in the above example it is sent to the function `setJsonLd` as a parameter, instead of a dependency of service itself. To fix this, inject `Renderer2` in your component first (NOT the service). Then, inject the service in your component. Finally, call the service function `setJsonLd` with `Renderer2` as a parameter (in the above example, it is the first parameter). Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, thank you for solving this. I only needed the client-side implementation

Comment: Awesome! i have been searching this for ages. The Angular SSR gives lots of headache! i never know tht renderer2 even exist :D

Comment: I am using Angular 2 and getting error "Render2 is not exported". I need to add schema in Angular 2 dynamically in component.

Comment: @ManeeshRao That's correct. Angular 2 does not provide a `Renderer2` yet. You can see this in the [documentation archive of Angular 2](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?query=renderer). You can either use the available `Renderer` in Angular 2 or upgrade your Angular version in order to use `Renderer2`. Hope this helps!

Comment: People here in Feb 2022 
Thank you @Nicky for the leads and nice explanation... new comers I found this nice small article explained in details with code snippets https://www.htmlgoodies.com/javascript/loading-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular/ Cheers :-)

Answer (score 26):

There is no Angular2 way of adding a script tag to a template.

Using `require(...)` to load external scripts from the components class was mentioned as a workaround (haven't tried it myself)

To dynamically add a script tag use

```
constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {};

ngAfterViewInit() {
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.src = "http://somedomain.com/somescript";
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
}
```

See also [angular2: including thirdparty js scripts in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570746/angular2-including-thirdparty-js-scripts-in-component/35570783#35570783)

Comment: You can't use external scripts with JSON-LD script tags either way as crawlers will not acknowledge it. The script needs to contain inline data. You haven't seen _any_ ways of outputting arbitrary data before Günter?

Realistically, this limitation means that no angular2 app will be able to do structured data for SEO in the way that Google recommends it.

Comment: Can you please post a link to that Google SEO recommendation?

Comment: I'd create a bug report for this use case.

Comment: I've added a comment to the original issue where it was decided to _strip_ tags instead of making them _inert_ or otherwise. Cheers for having a look!

Comment: JSON-LD is supported since a while by Angular and it won't strip such script tags.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer do you have an example? My script tags still get stripped in `4.0.2`

Comment: Can't imagine if you use my code above. If you use different code I'd suggest you create a new question and share your code.

Answer (score 22):

### The following works with Angular 5.2.7:

### The required imports are:

```
import { Inject, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
```

### Implement AfterViewInit:

```
export class HeroesComponent implements AfterViewInit {
```

If your component is implementing more that one interfaces, separate them by comma; for example:

```
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
```

### Pass the below arguments to constructor:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document, private elementRef: ElementRef) { }
```

### Add ngAfterViewInit method of view life-cycle:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const s = this.document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = '//external.script.com/script.js';
    const __this = this; //to store the current instance to call 
                         //afterScriptAdded function on onload event of 
                         //script.
    s.onload = function () { __this.afterScriptAdded(); };
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
  }
```

### Add afterScriptAdded member function.

This function will be called after the external script is loaded successfully. So the properties or functions you want to use from external js will be accessed in the body of this function.

```
 afterScriptAdded() {
    const params= {
      width: '350px',
      height: '420px',
    };
    if (typeof (window['functionFromExternalScript']) === 'function') {
      window['functionFromExternalScript'](params);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think, with the fat arrow syntax, you wont need the `_this = this` to access the class object.  You can do so like this, `s.onload =  ()=>  { this.afterScriptAdded(); };`

Answer (score 11):

**Actually** 
There is no **Angular2** way of adding a **script tag** to a template.
but you can do some **trick**
**first of all** you will import `AfterViewInit` and `ElementRef` from angular2
like this :

```
import {Component,AfterViewInit,ElementRef} from 'Angular2/core';
```

**then** you will you will implement them in your class like that :

```
export class example1 implements AfterViewInit{}
```

and here is a very simple javascript dom trick you gonna do

```
 export class example1 implements AfterViewInit{
 ngAfterViewInit()
 {
  var s=document.createElement("script");
  s.type="text/javascript";
  s.innerHTML="console.log('done');"; //inline script
  s.src="path/test.js"; //external script
 }
}
```

Comment: This works the first time but if you navigate away from the page and come back the script doesn't refire. Thoughts?

Comment: This worked for me. I am using Ionic with Angular and the issue of the script not firing again is due to the variables being assigned when it already exists so it throws a console error. I implemented the above logic in `ionViewDidEnter()` and added `window.location.reload();` in `ionViewWillLeave()` to force a refresh to get rid of the previous assignments. 

With this logic, routing to different tabs will make sure the script is always fired.

Answer (score 3):

```
const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
const _js = document.createElement('script');
_js.type = 'text/javascript';
_js.appendChild(document.createTextNode('{your js code here}'));
head.appendChild(_js);
```

this can be placed anywhere one wishes and it's a good approach

Comment: this is good and simple solution - but for me it worked only in ngAfterViewInit

Answer (score 2):

I added js script loading dynamically with condition inside of component init life hook in next way:

```
    private loadChatWithScript() {
    let chatScript = document.createElement("script");
    chatScript.type = "text/javascript";
    chatScript.async = true;
    chatScript.src = "https://chat-assets.frontapp.com/v1/chat.bundle.js";
    document.body.appendChild(chatScript);

    let chatScriptConfiguration = document.createElement("script");
    chatScriptConfiguration.type = "text/javascript";
    chatScriptConfiguration.async = true;
    chatScriptConfiguration.innerHTML = "window.FCSP = 'some-key-123'";
    document.body.appendChild(chatScriptConfiguration);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Gentleman/Gentlewoman, please take a look.

For adding a **Pixel Scripts** this may save you time, This solution is easier than any elaboration:

**- Only Works on First Loaded Page -**

Find `index.html` inside your Angular project, adjust it to something like this (put your script in the script tag):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Angular Application</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script>
  // Put your script here
  alert('Test me, Angular hero!');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

For using a script inside an angular component template, I suggest @Nicky's answer.