# bypassSecurityTrustHtml and bypassSecurityTrustScript in Angular2 with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to execute javascript function inside my Angular2 file via component. But I can't get this working.

This is how my ts file looks like.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import { JavaScriptService } from './javascript.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-javascript',
  template: `
     <div [innerHtml]="html"></div>
  `
})
export class JavaScriptService{

  html: any;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

  this.html = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<div><script type="text/javascript"> alert('h');</script></div>`);

  }

}
```

This is how html looks when Angular renders page in browser (I inspected elemens)

```
<div ng-reflect-inner-h-t-m-l="<div><script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;> alert('h');</script></div>">
<div><script type="text/javascript"> alert('h');</script></div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why alert is not executing after page is loaded.

I have tried both with bypassSecurityTrustHtml and bypassSecurityTrustScript but no luck. I appreciate if anyone have solution for this.

Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK script tags can't be added using `innerHTML`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088996/adding-script-tags-in-angular2-component-template/38090157#38090157 for how to add a script tag.

Comment: I also need help on this.

Comment: did this get resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this done before in your .ts file.

It will execute your script tag.

`const fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(yourHtmlString);
document.body.appendChild(fragment);`

Even though it works, then I get this issue SafeValue must use [property]=binding: (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss) being appended to my page so I'm working on resolving that.