# Angular render dynamiclly appended <script>-tag in component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I was trying to inject HTML template in an angular component DOM. These HTML template contains a `<div>`-tag and `<script>`-tag.

template.html

```
<div>Some Text</div>
<script>(function() { alert("I am here!"); })()</script>
```

When I use pure angular to do that within the `TestComponent`.

test-comp.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: "[test-comp]",
  templateUrl: "./test-comp.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./test-comp.component.css"]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  private _snippet: SafeHtml;

  get snippet(): SafeHtml { return this._snippet; }

  constructor(
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const template: string = require("module/dist/template.html");
    this._snippet = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(template);
  }
}
```

Component HTML looks like:

test-comp.component.html

```
<div id="some_id" [innerHTML]="snippets"></div>
```

This will inject the template correctly within the DOM, but the `<script>`-tag will not be implemented and it will not alert anything.

If I use jQuery to inject the same template into the same component so the `<script>`-tag will be implemented and it will alert the text.

test-comp.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: "[test-comp]",
  templateUrl: "./test-comp.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./test-comp.component.css"]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const template: string = require("module/dist/template.html");
    $("#some_id").after(template);
  }
}
```

Is there any explanation for this phenomena? I am interested to know the difference! and why jQuery works?

***Note***: My question is not duplicated with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088996/adding-script-tags-in-angular2-component-template) as some poeple mark it, because I am asking: Why it renders with `jQuery` and not renders with `domSanitizer`. I am not asking: How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) - HTML is the language of the Angular template. Almost all HTML syntax is valid template syntax. The  element is a notable exception; it is forbidden, eliminating the risk of script injection attacks. In practice,  is ignored and a warning appears in the browser console. See the [Security](https://angular.io/guide/security) page for details.

---

However you can bypass security using : [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Comment: I am doing that ``this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(template)``, but still it does not work! Is that what you mean ?