# „Can't convert object to primitive value" in Internet Explorer

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer, typeerror

I'm coding a webpage with Angular 7. Everything workes fine in Chrome, but in IE get en Exception while running:

**Can't convert object to primitive value** (polyfills.ts)

I really don't know where exactly the error came from....

I already found a Thread, where it says, that all Classes need a toString Method, so i added one, but this doesn't worked. Also i removed every ${}... Nothing.

IE Konsole: [IE-Konsole](https://pasteboard.co/Ihd9ifE.png)

Debugger: [Debugger](https://pasteboard.co/Ihd9CFu.png)

Comment: Have you uncommented codes from polyfills.ts?

Comment: First, please check the polyfills.ts file and make sure you have un-commented the related import for the IE browser. Second, you could try to add some debugger or console log to check the value whether it contains null, you could refer to [this article](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19435).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Belive it or not, but the problem was this line in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&language=de_DE"></script>
```

Removing it worked. But i need it, so i added dynamicly via javascript. This worked... Thats so random^^

Comment: This is what I'm fighting as well. How are you loading it dynamically via javascript?

Comment: There are many Solutions online, for Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43559644/10908838