# How can I add external JS file in Angular CLI component, specific to the component only?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli-v9

I have components Home and About in Angular CLI app. I have included the javascript file required for both components in **angular.json**. But I want to add component-specific javascript files in the component. Say, I want to add home.js to the Home component. Is there any way possible?

I have tried adding script into DOM using this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43559644/3701911), However, I want to add external js files instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
import * as test from 'test.js';

export class HomeComponent {
    ngOnInit() {
       test.testFunction(); //testFunction is in home.js
   }
}

// test.js
export function testFunction() {
    console.log('hello world');
}
```

Please refer to this answer: [Angular 2: import external js file into component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081943/angular-2-import-external-js-file-into-component)

Comment: The file is loaded but functions inside home.js are unaccessible.

Comment: Did you export your function in home.js?@Jaspal

Comment: Can you provide some detailed info about your home.js. Or just create a simple `test.js` file with `testFunction` as I mentioned in the answer for testing the connection?@Jaspal

Comment: thanks, buddy it's working perfectly. I forgot to add the namespace test before calling function.