# Dynamically add ld+json schema in angular SPA index.html

Tags: angular, single-page-application, ld, schema.org

I'm working on an angular app. Every page of my app is, basically, index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="/my-app/">
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link...>
    <script> ... </script>
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to add a schema.org's DataCatalog to this but with dynamic values. Imagine I've a list of items displayed, each item has a name, I want those names to appear in the DataCatalog's keywords (just imagine):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="/my-app/">
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link...>
    <script> ... </script>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "DataCatalog",
            "description": "MyApp Description",
            "keywords": [
                "dynamicValue1",
                "dynamicValue2"
            ],
            "license": "https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html",
            "name": "MyApp",
            ...
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me on how to do this? I feel like I've search the whole internet and no one seems to have a similar issue.

What I've tried:

Add :

```
<script type="application/ld+json" src="src/datacatalog.json"></script>
```

in index.html and fill datacatalog.json. It doesn't seem to work, when I check the page source code, datacatalog.json seems unknown. When I right-click and save the target, I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /src/datacatalog.json</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what to do with this.

Also tried to programatically add the script in an Angular component (from another SO thread I saw) but it did nothing.

Thank you

Comment: Follow this advice from Trevor Fox: https://trevorfox.com/2017/03/json-ld-files-with-javascript/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding script tags in Angular component template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088996/adding-script-tags-in-angular-component-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manage to solve my issue with the help of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088996/adding-script-tags-in-angular-component-template)

Basically, you can write in index.html from an angular component. The component loaded just happens to be the one making request to my backend to get all the data I need to fill the schema.

Schema.org and google's validator recognize my schema and it works well.